# Joomla website error exception.php on line 117

Tags: joomla

Please anyone suggest how to fix this issue in joomla website

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41 bytes) in /home/content/46/8440746/html/libraries/joomla/error/exception.php on line 117

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase memory limit of PHP

Comment: Thanks Gaurav,Actually I don't know where to edit the PHP file not more techical so if possible help me with steps then can try to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+increase+php+memory+limit Check the link, if any topic helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with the name `php.ini`

set the value like `memory_limit = 80M` same the file and put this php.ini file
into the administrator folder, Structure like:

```
joomla/administrator/php.ini
```

in the above structure the file `php.ini` is yours

**Edit:** the `memory_limit` you will change according to you
the above limit is just an example